# autoValue not working when you validate against mongodb collection fields

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I am trying to set a value using autoValue based on already stored values
I am using meteor 1.3.4.1

This used to work in meteor 1.1.0.2

here is my code:

```
    id: { 
    type: String,
    label: "ID",
    autoValue: function() {
        var isFirstTime = this.field("profile.isFirstTime").value;
        var isApproved = this.field("profile.changesApproved").value; 
        var value = this.field("profile.unapproved_id").value;
        var userId = this.userId;
        var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId});
        if (user && user.profile && user.profile.id)
        {
            return user.profile.id;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect value of user.profile.id to be returned since user.profile.id has a value in the users collection but I get a value that is passed from input field. How do I get simple-schema to notice collection values as it used to on meteor 1.1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusing part here is the 'this' keyword. in the context of the autoValue function(), this may be the object itself, unless some other context is bound to it by SimpleSchema.

So  would suggest you trace the code with debugger and check what is the value of this. if it is not what you think it is, check where it is defined

Comment: There is no issue with the 'this' object. The issue I experience is with the if statement. I traced the code with the debugger and it seems to return the value in user.profile.id but when processing ends id does not have the value in user.profile.id . It has the value captured in the input

Comment: then maybe you need to use AutoForm hooks instead of autoValue:
with `Autoform.hooks({"id_of_form": { before: { method: function(doc) {..your code here }}});` you can manipulate the document between the submission by the user and the submission to the server.